# React Native and node js - fetching input values and using them in controllers

Tags: node.js, react-native, controller, asyncstorage

I have a react native component that has username and password text input fields. I want the values which are entered to be available in the node js controller to query my db. I am not able to use AsyncStorage as I cannot import AsyncStorage inside controller. How do I make this work? Please help.

My login screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
Image,
TextInput,
Alert,
Navigator,
TouchableHighlight,
BackAndroid,
ScrollView,
AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';

var _navigator;

import Container from './Container';
import Button from './Button';
import Label from './Label';
import ImageContainer from './ImageContainer';
import RegisterView from './RegisterView';


export default class LoginView extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
 this.state = {
  userName: '',
  userPass: '',
  error:null,
};
}


_navigate(){
this.props.navigator.push({
name: 'RegisterView', // Matches route.name
})

}
_handleAdd = () => {

if((this.state.userName)!=="" && (this.state.userPass)!=="" ){
  const data = {
    username: this.state.userName,
    password: this.state.userPass
 }
  // Serialize and post the data
  const json = JSON.stringify(data)
  fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/users/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: json
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.error) {
      alert(res.error)
    } else {
     this.props.navigator.push({
         name: 'CheckList', // Matches route.name
       })
    }
  })
  .catch(() => {
    alert('There was an error logging in.');
  })
  .done()
  }
  else{
      alert('Cannot be empty!');
      }
  }


render() {
return (
<ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>

    <ImageContainer>

    <Image
              style={{width:110,height: 110, justifyContent: 'center',       
   alignItems: 'center'}}
              source={require('./Logo.png')}>
              </Image>
     </ImageContainer>

<Container>
<TextInput
    placeholder="Username"
    style={styles.textInput}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({userName:text})}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
       const{userName}=this.state.userName;
       const{onSubmitEditing}=this.props;
        if(!userName) return
        onSubmitEditing(userName)
        this.refs.SecondInput.focus();
      }}

   />

<TextInput
    placeholder="Password"
    ref='SecondInput'
    secureTextEntry={true}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({userPass:text})}
    style={styles.textInputPass}
/>
</Container>

         <Container>
             <Button
                 label="Sign In"
                 styles={{button: styles.primaryButton, label:   
 styles.buttonWhiteText}}
                 onPress={() => this._handleAdd()}
                  />
         </Container>
         <Container>
         <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this._navigate()}
          underlayColor= 'transparent'>
             <Text style ={styles.buttonBlackText}>New? Register    
</Text>
         </TouchableHighlight>
         </Container>

    </ScrollView>

);

  }

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
scroll: {
backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
padding: 30,
flexDirection: 'column'
},

buttonWhiteText: {
fontSize: 20,
color: '#FFF'
},

buttonBlackText: {
fontSize: 20,
marginTop: 20,
textAlign:'center',
color: '#000000'
},


textInput: {
fontSize: 20,
backgroundColor: '#FFF',
marginBottom: 20,
marginTop: 20
},

textInputPass: {
fontSize: 20,
backgroundColor: '#FFF',
marginBottom: 20,
},
primaryButton: {
backgroundColor: '#34A853'
},


});
```

Controller to query the username from db. For now, it's hardcoded.

```
import Profile from '../models/profile';
import moment from 'moment';


export const index = (req, res, next) => {
Profile.find({'username': 'John'}).lean().exec((err, profiles) =>     
res.json(
// Iterate through each movie
    { profiles: profiles.map(profile => ({
      ...profile,
 }))}
));
};
```